# Using Select-K-best on unknown test-set

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I trained a logistic regression classifier in sklearn. My base feature-file has 65 features, now I extrapolated them to a 1000 by considering quadratic combinations also (using PolynomialFeatures()). And then I reduced them back to 100 by Select-K-Best() method.

However, once I have my model trained and I get a new test_file, it would only have the 65 base features but my model expects 100 of them.

So, how can I apply the Select-K-Best() method on my test-set when I do not know the labels which is required in Select-K-Best.fit() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't fit SelectKBest again on test data - use the same (already fit) SelectKBest instance as in training instead. I.e. you should only use .transform method on test data, not .fit method.

scikit-learn provides an utility which makes managing multiple steps like that easier; it is called [Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html). It should be something like that in your case (via [make_pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html) helper):

```
pipe = make_pipeline(
    PolynomialFeatures(2), 
    SelectKBest(100), 
    LogisticRegression()
)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks! 

In my case I need to persist the model(save to a file) after training and then load again for testing. 

So I guess I should also save the fit'ed SelectKBest to a file and load it for testing .
Currently I am storing the numpy array (which contains the indices to the K-features selected)  to a file and load it during testing.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Just dump (using pickle or joblib) the whole Pipeline object, i.e. `pipe` variable. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#model-persistence for more details.